# Auto-submit exposed form

Tags: views, 8, ajax

I'm currently working on a views exposed form block. I want the form to auto-submit using AJAX, whenever an exposed filter is changed.

I have searched for this, but I couldn't find any tutorial or guide. 
I cannot see any setting in the view, so I guess I have to implement  `hook_form_alter`. Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the answer myself. Using the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module did the trick.

From the module's description:

> Provide instant feedback by updating the View using AJAX whenever an exposed filter is changed.